# cannot see changes made in remote mysql over site

Tags: mysql, remote-server

I have remote MySQL database on UAT server i can connect to database and have made some changes. I can see changes made in database after refresh but it is not reflecting on website.

And on my local computer same changes made in MySQL phpmyadmin, I can see it on site.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like maybe there is a caching issue at work here.  Can you include more information about your site, how it works, and how it connects to the database?

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for reply, I am using codeigniter so connecting database with its database config file. I recently take over this sites work so in process of finding it's way of working but as far as I know it's not a caching problem with this particular issue, sorry I am quite new to Mysql, do i need to restart mysql to see changes?